# How to click on a button using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm making some test with selenium on this page:
https://www.justwatch.com/es/proveedor/hbo-max/peliculas

The first time you get in the page you must accept the privacy settings but I cannot get it to work. I've tried all the methods I now but it seems like I can't find the button I want so the program stops as the waiting time ends. The button I want to click is:

```
<button role="button" data-testid="uc-save-button" class="sc-gsDKAQ eaUldE" style="margin: 0px 6px;">Guardar configuración</button>
```

I tried to locate the button by text, class and using the XPath but doesnt work.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 5)\
.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'sc-gsDKAQ eaUldE'.replace(' ', '.'))))\
.click()

WebDriverWait(driver, 5)\
.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]//div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/button[1]')))\
.click()

WebDriverWait(driver, 5)\
.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, 'Guardar configuración')))\
.click()
```

I will appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

To click on the desired element you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[data-testid='uc-save-button']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@data-testid='uc-save-button' and text()='Guardar configuración']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: thanks for you answer but it didnt work. I tryed clicking on other elements of the page and it works, i think the problem may be caused by the button being on privacy settings pop up. Do you know if it may have anything to do with the issue